# Uncaught ReferenceError: Lawnchair is not defined

Tags: javascript, local-storage, lawnchair

I'm trying to get the [basic lawnchair example](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) working.

The Code:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/src/lawnchair.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var people = new Lawnchair('people');
</script>
```

Gives the following error (in FF & Chrome consoles):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Lawnchair is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know but I sure could use a `new Lawnchair()`...

Comment: My inability to spell is only the tip of the iceberg... Still can't get it to work. Switched to ded's kizzy. Super easy... perfect for me

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a link.

Comment: Here's the Kizzy I was talking about: https://github.com/ded/Kizzy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled "javascript" in the first `<script>` tag's "type" attribute. The browser therefore paid no attention to the file.

Many people, most of them attractive and popular, now recommend leaving off the "type" attribute entirely unless you explicitly *want* the browser to ignore the contents.

Comment: Attractive and popular JS programmers? That's unpossible!

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got a typo in the first script tag. 'text/javscript' = 'text/javascript

Answer (score 1):

Actually that example is no longer valid as of the current build. Take a look at this check in.
[Require a callback in the Lawnchair constructor.](https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair/blob/1ddca5f351c232fd732d514aae36a672bf30ee60/src/Lawnchair.js)

I'm still trying to get it straight myself but the constructor requires a callback in addition to the object passed in. I'll post what I got when its working.

Comment: Cool, if you post the solution, I'll add it to the question as an update.

Comment: were u able to get this to work??

Comment: what I ended up doing was using the version that was in the site tutorial on http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

Comment: That did work however it seemed like more than what was necessarily required for me. After dealing with that I decided to just use straight HTML5 local storage and parsing my converting my objects back and forth between json and string.